# Is Eureka a commune?

Tags: economics, eureka

The town seems to be as economically isolated as it is in all other ways. The DOD funds Global Dynamics, but otherwise it would appear to be a money-less society: houses and businesses are built and rebuilt, vehicles are upgraded and replaced frequently, tech is freely borrowed and re-purposed, the bank contains technical and personal artifacts. Most notably food from Cafe Diem is explicitly free. Everyone in town seems to have their own niche job with no competition. In fact I don't recall money ever being mentioned other than the government funding GD.

So is the lack of money just an oversimplification of a company town, or there some kind of communal economy in effect? Have the creators ever addressed this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Jack Carter](http://eureka.wikia.com/wiki/Jack_Carter) certainly receives a salary (explictly mentioned in the Pilot episode when he's advised that his new job as 'Sheriff of Eureka' comes with both a promotion and a **pay rise**) and [Zane Donovan](http://eureka.wikia.com/wiki/Zane_Donovan) gets into trouble for removing funds from Eureka's bank to give to his old Teacher in the episode "E = MC...?" so clearly they don't live in a totally cashless environment.

I think if you think of the town as a gigantic technology campus (like the "Googleplex" or Microsoft's Campus in Redmond) it all makes a lot more sense...

Some of the stores on the main street do seem to be offering "sale prices" and low-interest financing so it seems the idea of Eureka being a "commune" boils down to the subsidised canteen.

[image]

Comment: +1. It's a standard high-tech R&D hub. Dialed up to 11. The economic output of an off-the-scale genius is significantly higher than a cost of a house in a small isolated community outside Real Estate bubbles, or a price of a few lunches in a cafe. So these perks are merely part of what HR refers to "total comp"

Comment: Plus, do we really see anyone actually shopping for anything? I can't recall a single instance where anyone goes to buy milk or clothing although there are stores along the main strip.

Comment: FreshDirect.com and Amazon. It's a 2000s show